# UITableView -insertRowsAtIndexPaths: performance with UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I would like to insert a UITableViewCell with an UIDatePicker in to my tableview.

I am doing so using the following code:

```
        NSIndexPath *insert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = insert;
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[insert] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

The cell is a simple UITableViewCell subclass defined in a nib with a UIDatePicker placed in the contentView.

I'm finding that I am encountering performance issues with the animation - When the date picker is to be displayed, I'm getting a jerky animation. Hiding the datePicker presents no such issues.

I profiled the animation, and it appears a heavy amount of work is being done in the UIDatePicker's layoutSubviews.

Has anyone been able to overcome performance issues when animating with UIDatePicker? How can I improve the performance here?

thanks

**UPDATE**

It appears as though the date picker is not the issue.

After profiling in Core Animation Instruments, the frame rate appears to drop whether the cell has a date picker or not. Even a blank cell is not performant. I am having difficulty tracking down what exactly is causing the cell's insertion to jump.

**UPDATE**

It appears as though it animates smoothly for 44pts but if I make it larger it jumps. Implementing the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

appears to resolve the issue